# How to change the drawing order of a layout children in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

By default in Jetpack Compose a layout children rendering order matches the order of the children in the code. In the following example the ship (Text) will be drawn over the water (Box).

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DrawingOrderExample(submarineMode: Boolean) {
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(32.dp)
                .background(Color.Cyan.copy(alpha = .5f))
        )

        Text("⛵")
    }
}
```

Can I force the ship to be drawn under the water according to `submarineMode` argument?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [zIndex()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/package-summary#zindex) modifier to change the children drawing order:

```kotlin
...

import androidx.compose.ui.zIndex

Box {
    Text("Drawn second", Modifier.zIndex(1f))
    Text("Drawn first")
}
```

The ship example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DrawingOrderExample(submarineMode: Boolean) {
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(32.dp)
                .background(Color.Cyan.copy(alpha = .5f))
        )

        val shipZIndex = if (submarineMode) -1f else 1f

        Text(
            text = "⛵",
            modifier = Modifier.zIndex(shipZIndex) // <- here's the trick
        )
    }
}
```

Now `submarineMode` argument affects the drawing order:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I really like this answer with the boat

Comment: And `.zIndex(3f)` might locate/will be more higher, when element with `.zIndex(1f)`

Answer (score -7):

Just wrap the Box in an if statement and create two boxes each for the if and the else block. It is no harm

Comment: Isn't that 3 more objects in memory than the z-Index option?